# Bind9 configuration issues

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have set up a bind9 DNS server on my server. I have it configured correctly as far as resolving my web server. I also installed an IRC server on this machine and for some reason I can connect to the IRC by /server mysite.com but if I use /server irc.mysite.com I cannot resolve the IRC server. Where in my configurations do I need to add the irc entry and is it an A, NS, PTR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map a hostname to an IP address, you use an A record. It should go within the configuration for your domain (known as a *zone*).

```
irc     IN      A       198.51.100.243
```